# How to check pushed and popped counts for a redis-queue using reis-cli

Tags: debugging, redis

I am using `redis` to send and receive data between different application. However, I found when an application `push` thousands of data to a queue, the other application implementing `pop` has incomplete data!

To identify the problem - I added counters at `push` and `pop` and found that `pop` counter to be less than pushed also I don't see any pending message in the same queue when pop has finished executing.

I am trying to dig where is the data getting lost. What are the ways I should try? Is there any command in `redis-cli` which can show the pushed and pop count for a given queue

Answer (score 1):

You can use MONITOR command from redis-cli. Pipe the output to a file and then you should be quite easily to see how many hand landed in Redis. Another advice is use sequential numbers to debug your problem it's easier to see which one is missing.